# MySQL Query to get row with least amount of data?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have this:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | name
1  | xxx  | xxx  | xxx  |      | xxx  | John
2  |      |      |      | xxx  | xxx  | Peter
3  | xxx  | xxx  | xxx  |      |      | Sam
```

How would I get a result like this:

```
id | filledData | name
1  | 4          | John
2  | 2          | Peter
3  | 3          | Sam
```

Basically, there are set columns that I want to use to determine how "well populated" the data is, and then sort them by that, so that I can try and fill the columns with the least amount of data first?

Comment: Why do you store the amount in several columns? Sounds like your table isn't properly normalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if the column is null or not using `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT  ID,
        name,
        CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN col3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN col4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN col5 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END filledData
FROM    tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0918a/3)

Answer (score 0):

This requires a complicated case statement:

```
select id, filledData, name
from (select t.*,
             ((case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when col4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when col5 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
             ) as filledData
      from t
     ) t
```